# Is a get request possible with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, frontend, backend

I was wondering if it was possible to make a GET request with javascript, so it can update text without refreshing the page.

If this is possible, how can I make a get request with javascript & get the result/decode it from json?

I tried this from a past question:

```
function updateButton(){

    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://xxxx.com/getSpecialSale.php", false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("dicebutton").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

And, it completely stops the main thread, making the website unresponsive. What is wrong?

Comment: Don't pass `false` to [`xmlHttp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open)

Comment: Async is set to false (third param of `.open`), so it will lock up the UI until it completes.  Your code will need modification to work with async true.

Comment: Yes - But why would aysnc be needed to GET data? It is not performance I'm worried about, the script is not working even though it should on the main thread.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether `GET` or `POST`; async is needed to not bring JS to a screeching halt while waiting for the server's reply. Still, can you clarify what the issue is? Is the website unresponsive for a short time? Or does it crash completely?

Comment: AJAX requests should be asynchronous.  Fix that first.  Is there any problem after that?

Comment: @JavaC3code it's not working with async, because you are not waiting for the response. You have to register and callback, which waits for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you set the async parameter to false, so the request is sent to the server and the browser waits for the response. To make an async request, just pass true as thrid param to `open`

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://xxxx.com/getSpecialSale.php", true);
```

in addition to that, you have to register an callback, which waits for the response (and maybe to handle errors..)

```
xmlHttp.onload = function (e) {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status === 200) {
            console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
        } else {
           console.error(xmlHttp.statusText);
        }
    }
};
xmlHttp.onerror = function (e) {
    console.error(xmlHttp.statusText);
};
```

In addition to that a note from the mozilla docs

> Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 /
>   SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been
>   deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.

Comment: he also needs to move the code that uses `responseText` to a callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isAjax=false;
function updateButton(){
     if(!isAjax) { //Stops the user making a million requests per minute
        isAjax=true;
        var xmlHttp = null;

        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://xxxx.com/getSpecialSale.php", true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("dicebutton").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        isAjax=false;
    }
}
```

OR jQuery...

```
$("#btnUpdate").click(function(){
    $.get("http://xxxx.com/getSpecialSale.php", function(data, status){
        $("#dicebutton").html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use async you will need some code modifications, ie the stuff that happens after the response completes needs to be in a callback function as follows:

```
function updateButton(){

    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://xxxx.com/getSpecialSale.php", true);
    xmlHttp.onload = function () {
      document.getElementById("dicebutton").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    };
    xmlHttp.send(null);

}
```